# Como concatenar una linea y mostrarla en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de concatenar una linea, y después mostrarla en mi datagridview, mi idea seria mostrar las mesas 1, 2, 3 en una misma linea..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo par cargar este datagrid es:

```
private void CargarReservas()
{
  clsReservas res = new clsReservas();
  V_DetallesReserva det = new V_DetallesReserva();
  string estadoReserva = "Reservado";
  string estadoMesaxReserva = "Pendiente";
  List<V_DetallesReserva> lst = 
  res.LeerListadoDetalleReservaDisponibles(estadoReserva, estadoMesaxReserva);
  foreach (V_DetallesReserva item in lst)
  {
    this.dtgvDetRese.Rows.Add(item.ID_Detalle.ToString(), 
    item.ID_Reserva.ToString(), item.Numero_Mesa.ToString(), item.Fecha, 
    item.Hora, item.Detalle, item.Estado, item.Cliente, item.DNI, 
    item.Teléfono, item.E_Mail, item.EstadoMXR);
  }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias !!

Comment: Cuantas filas de la tabla quiere concatenar en una misma linea del DataGridView?

Comment: según la cantidad de mesas que haya, ese datagrid es de una reserva, y a lo mejor me pueden reservar 10, 2 o solo 1 mesa..

Comment: Es correcto que quiere lograr algo como [esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK47r.png)?